# How to check if array contains number

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I'm building an ATM and I have a method in my second class that is suppose to check the login pin to see if it exists in the `ArrayList`. Though I am new to java and I am not sure on how to do this? I am trying to use `arraylistname.contains` but I'm not sure if that is right. I will post both my classes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankMain {
    ArrayList<Integer> cardNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         BankMain main = new BankMain();
         main.menu();
    }

    public void cardNumbers(){
        Scanner cards = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please select a 5 digit card number");
        cardNum.add(input.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Thank you! You're card number is " +cardNum);
        System.out.println("Type 'c' to go back to main menu.");
        String value  = keyboard.next();
        if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
            menu();
        }else if (!keyboard.equals('c')){
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry!");
        }
    }

    public void menu(){
        System.out.println("What Would you like to do today?");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Create Account = 1");
        System.out.println("Login = 2");
        System.out.println("Exit = 3");
        query();
    }

    public void query(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double input = keyboard.nextInt();  

        if (input == 2){
            BankMainPart2 main2 = new BankMainPart2();
            System.out.println("Please enter your 5 digit card number.");
            main2.loginCard(cardNum);
        }else if (input == 1){
            cardNumbers();
        }else if (input == 3){
            System.out.println("Thank you, have a nice day!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
   }
}
```

And, here's my second class, with the login method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BankMainPart2 {
    public static void loginCard(ArrayList<Integer> cardNum){
        if (cardNum.contains(0)) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it works, but let's reveal the man behind the curtain here.

What's going on is called [autoboxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Autoboxing).  The method you want to use requires an object type.  `int` is **not** an object type, but `Integer` *is*.  In fact, all primitive types have a boxed object associated with them.

Java will happily convert your primitive to a boxed object automatically.  This can get dicey, since some internals in Java can play fast and loose, and `Short` autoboxing is just plain weird, so be careful where and when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works fine if you are doing lookup on `int` (primitive types), which is your case.

This may give you wrong results if you do lookup by passing mutable object unless you override `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
  cardNum.contains(0)
                   ^^^^   //It should be Card number entered by user.
```

It works because of `autoboxing` as stated in `Makoto's` Answer.